# Prolog decomposition returning a period

Tags: prolog

I have a predicate that decomposes an expression and I am having results that I dont understand when I trace through it.

My predicate is as below

```
 calc(R,Expr) :- Expr =..[Op,H,T].
```

So when I have an expression like [1,1], the Op is actually a period. Any idea why?

Comment: A [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10022779/prolog-unusual-cons-syntax-for-lists/) you might be interested in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because the form `[Head|Tail]` is just syntactic sugar for `'.'(Head, Tail)` (everything is a term and lists are no exception). Normally, for the list made of `1`, `2`, `3` and `4`, you'd have to write

```
'.'(1, '.'(2, '.'(3, '.'(4, [])))).
```

As you can see, that's not very practical and instead we use the shortcut:

```
[1|[2|[3|[4|[]]]]]
```

And this shortcut has a shortcut:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

And you can mix those as you wish:

```
[1, 2|[3, 4]]
```

That is handy when you want to specify some elements and then let the tail free:

```
[1, 2|A]
```

BTW, you can see that for yourself by using `write_canonical/1`:

```
?- write_canonical([1, 2, 3, 4]).
'.'(1,'.'(2,'.'(3,'.'(4,[]))))
true.
```

Hope it helped