# Can a Prolog sentence be ambiguous?

Tags: prolog

Is it possible for a Prolog sentence to be ambiguous and could you show me an example?

I know parsers can be ambiguous in a way that they could generate two different parse trees...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Prolog formally is not ambiguous, but is offers a syntactic feature that can lead to difficult to understand programs, namely the [op](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=op/3)/3 declaration. As you can read in documentation

> Applications must be careful with (re-)defining operators because changing operators may cause (other) files to be interpreted differently.

It's like C++ operator overloading on steroids, and the ability to define new operators (or redefine some already know to the system), can be very valuable when programming DSLs (domain specific languages). See for instance library([clpfd](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=clpfd)) or [lambda](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pack/list?p=lambda).

Of historical relevance, it's the dot operator. Its main use is as clause terminator, but the older Prolog used it as 'list cons'. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10023905/874024) is a mine answer about this topic. Note the initial declaration

```
:- op(103, xfy, (.)).
```

that allows a compact definition (for instance)

```
seek_call(A.As, _.Ms, B.As, V) :-
    nonvar(A),
    A =.. F.FAs,
    seek_call(FAs, Ms, FBs, V),
    !, B =.. F.FBs.
```

it's equivalent to

```
seek_call([A|As], [_|Ms], [B|As], V) :-
    nonvar(A),
    A =.. [F|FAs],
    seek_call(FAs, Ms, FBs, V),
    !, B =.. [F|FBs].
```

Comment: It's worth noting that if you used `xfx` instead, you could coerce an operator priority clash error out of Prolog by doing something like `X.Y.Z`. The ambiguity is "resolved" by the error though.

Comment: @DanielLyons: Not sure I understand. xfx is meant exactly to ban A op B op C. yfy is *not* allowed because it would lead to ambiguity.

Comment: I thought xfx meant the operator is non-associative, where xfy means right associative and yfx means left associative (IIRC). My point is just that the user can create ambiguity like this and Prolog resolves it with an error rather than multiple successful parses.